# Unity3d - How to add gameobject list to array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to list Gameobject to array.My gameobject have sub-mesh see image now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDCck.png

I want to list sub gameobject from name "b2_floor9_middleArea" to all.

I use c# Language

How do I put code for solve my problem ?

Comment: And besides adding your code, could you clarify what exactly it is you want to achieve?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you really want to do and what you already have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the game all of those sub meshes are child transforms.  Every transform is a container of child transforms, so you can loop over the transform children of a game object like this:

```
 GameObject g = Selection.activeGameObject;
if (g != null)
{
    Transform t  = g.transform;
    foreach (Transform sub in t)  
    {
        Debug.Log(sub); // do something with the sub here
    }

}
```

You can use [Transform.Find()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html)  To look for a named child transform.  More [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205391/how-to-get-list-of-child-game-objects.html) and [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/183649/how-to-find-a-child-gameobject-by-name.html)

To get all of the children, grandchildren etc use **GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren()** on the root GameObject.  That returns them all.